# IP Tables script for reading logs

Tags: linux, bash, grep, iptables

Need some help designing a bash script for grepping IP addresses from auth.log and apache.log that look dodgy so I can automatically add them to the IP logs.

Thinking of grepping both of these logs, but I need to know which's are dodgy.

At the moment I have a IP Table rule in place for ssh that block incoming connections but I need to block all these requests for w00t, phpadmin, etc.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If for some reason you don't want to use an already made tool for such task like [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page), you can use the **[regexps](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Apache)** provided in that tool as an excellent starting point.

Comment: Thanks the reply, yep I'm looking at fail2ban at the moment however I'm a tad confused on how to stop it from blocking IP address that are in the /var/www/dev folder as this will show many errors and files not exist which I dont what the IP to be banned Cheers